# Better way to determine required storage for []byte

Tags: go, slice, sizeof

I've got a bit of code that unpacks a message read from a UDP socket including the devices MAC address (which the device stores in the message itself). I have found that just assigning the `[]byte` slice to the struct member copies the address of the MAC address in the buffer. I can copy the value using the `copy()` primitive and that only works if I first allocate storage in the destination. The following code works:

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

// information about an Orvibo S20 IoT device
type Device struct {
    Mac, ReverseMac net.HardwareAddr // MAC address (and reversed)
    IsOn            bool             // power state
}

// function to unpack the info from the Discover reply
func unpackDiscoverResp(buff []byte) Device {
    d := Device{}
    d.Mac = make([]byte, 6)
    copy(d.Mac, buff[7:7+6])
    d.ReverseMac = make([]byte, 6)
    copy(d.ReverseMac, buff[7+12:7+6+12])
    d.IsOn = buff[41] != 0
    return d
}

func main() {
    s1 := []byte{
        0x68, 0x64, 0x00, 0x2a, 0x71, 0x61, 0x00, 0xac, 0xcf, 0x23, 0x36, 0x02, 0x0e, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
        0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0e, 0x02, 0x36, 0x23, 0xcf, 0xac, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x53,
        0x4f, 0x43, 0x30, 0x30, 0x35, 0x2e, 0xe1, 0x9d, 0xdc, 0x00}
    s2 := []byte{
        0x68, 0x64, 0x00, 0x2a, 0x71, 0x61, 0x00, 0xac, 0xcf, 0x23, 0x55, 0xfe, 0x22, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
        0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x22, 0xfe, 0x55, 0x23, 0xcf, 0xac, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x53,
        0x4f, 0x43, 0x30, 0x30, 0x35, 0x39, 0x87, 0x1b, 0xbc, 0x01}

    msgs := [][]byte{s1, s2}

    devices := make([]Device, 0)

    for _, msg := range msgs {
        d := unpackDiscoverResp(msg)
        devices = append(devices, d)
        fmt.Println(d)
    }

    //d1 := unpackDiscoverResp(s1)
    //devices = append(devices, d1)
    //d2 := unpackDiscoverResp(s2)
    //devices = append(devices, d2)
    //fmt.Println(d1)
    fmt.Println(devices)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vMdNlX5H2H
The part I don't like is line 19 (and 21)

```
d.Mac = make([]byte, 6)
```

It seems to me that this must be common pattern and there should be a way to get the size required for the storage. Since I've hard coded the slice length I'm copying from I suppose hard coding the storage required is no worse, but in the more general sense I'd prefer to do better. (In C I'd use the `sizeof` operator but this isn't C.)

Thanks!

Comment: Go also has [Sizeof](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof), but I don't think that will help you here.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `len()`?

```
newBuf := make([]byte,len(oldBuf))
copy(newBuf, oldBuf)
```

If you have more complex requirements, please explain them.

Answer (score 2):

In Go use the builtin [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) function. Store the result of slicing, and use `len()` on it:

```
func unpackDiscoverResp(buff []byte) Device {
    d := Device{}

    mac := buff[7:7+6]
    d.Mac = make([]byte, len(mac))
    copy(d.Mac, mac)

    reverseMac := buff[7+12:7+6+12]
    d.ReverseMac = make([]byte, len(reverseMac))
    copy(d.ReverseMac, reverseMac)

    d.IsOn = buff[41] != 0
    return d
}
```

But if you just want to make a copy of it, it's easier / shorter to just append to a `nil` slice (the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function allocates storage as needed):

```
func unpackDiscoverResp(buff []byte) Device {
    d := Device{}
    d.Mac = append(d.Mac, buff[7:7+6]...)
    d.ReverseMac = append(d.ReverseMac, buff[7+12:7+6+12]...)
    d.IsOn = buff[41] != 0
    return d
}
```

Or simply in the composite literal:

```
d := Device{
    Mac:        append([]byte(nil), buff[7:7+6]...),
    ReverseMac: append([]byte(nil), buff[7+12:7+6+12]...),
}
```

One thing to note here: `append()` might allocate a bigger backing array than what is needed (it "optimizes" for future appends), so if you want to avoid that, the first solution with `copy()` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - `len()` is the key. I replaced the original code with

```
// copyMac allocates space for and copies MAC addr from slice
func copyMac(dst *net.HardwareAddr, src []byte) {
    *dst = make([]byte, len(src))
    copy(*dst, src)
}

// Code to find and send commands to Orvibo S20 WiFi controlled outlets
// The outlets need to brought into the network first (AKA paired)
// and for that see pair.go
func unpackDiscoverResp(ip *net.UDPAddr, buff []byte) Device {
    d := Device{IpAddr: *ip}
    copyMac(&d.Mac, buff[7:7+6])
    copyMac(&d.ReverseMac, buff[7+12:7+6+12])
    d.IsOn = buff[41] != 0
    return d
}
```

I'm happier with that than my original code. (I do need to fix that comment which has lost its connection to the code.)